Why do NfcAntennaInfo.getAvailableNfcAntennas returns 2 antennas instead of 1?
I'm trying to access NFC information in my realme 11, especially its physical position. I tried https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAntennaInfo#getAvailableNfcAntennas() (I'm okay that it's only for sdkInt >= 34)
, but unexpectedly it returns 2 antennas on my phone: one that I'm actually using for NFC features (top left) and one that I see for the first time (above middle right).
I tried to obtain tags with last one and still didn't succeed. I'm concerned why is that, because I expected to get only active NFC antenna, like what does the second supposed to mean?
Link to image

Does the phone have wireless charging? Is the second location where the wireless charging is located? There are NFC and wireless charging chips available that can use the same antenna for both functions. May be the wireless charging hardware can do NFC but the hardware manufacturer also put in a dedicated NFC antenna/chip which is the default. Have you made a basic NFC detector of a couple of loops of wire connected to each leg of an LED to see if the second antenna is polling and sending power?
